# How hide link info when bot telegram sends a link to user php?

Tags: php, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

How can hide a link info at the bottom of the post in telegram bot?
for example i try below code:

```html
<?php

$txt1="<a href='yahoo.com'>yahoo website</a>";
$url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendMessage?parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".urlencode($txt1);
file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

but

> it shows yahoo info at bottom of the post

how can i delete that info?

please help me.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use [disable_web_page_preview](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?sendMessage-81307a85).

Comment: tnx thats true dude ;)

Comment: how can use it for sending photo or video?

Comment: @a.programmer Oh, I see your new question :)